# maven resource from multiple source directory

Tags: maven

I have a web project which has a specific resource directory structure similar to below.

- client
- abc
- xyz

The *client* directory contains all the basic file required for the project. The other directories are client-specific override. Currently, in order to run the website for the client abc, I have to manually copy files from *client* directory into the *abc* folder and make sure that I don't accidentally overwrite the file in *abc*, as the web framework does not support resource overrides by any mean.

On top of that, I don't have access to the web framework code, and it's currently unmaintained. I can't change the framework to support the resource override, unfortunately.

My company decided that we want to make use of Maven to automate the build process. I have no control over this decision. Anyway, I'm not really familiar with Maven, I need some advice on how to archive the resource preparing task mentioned above.

I do have a Gradle script to automate the build. Unfortunately, it's not accepted by the company (we don't want to use too many tools to do the same thing). I've written the resource preparing task in Gradle to do the following step:-

1. make a copy of *client* directory
2. rename the *abc* directory to a temporary name (eg. abc.org)
3. rename the directory created in 1. to *abc*.
4. copy all file from 2. to the directory *abc* (the one created in 1.)

I don't know if I can use the same approach in Maven or not though. Just put it here as a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For low level copying of directories, I prefer the maven-antrun-plugin and write some copy and move commands in Ant.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html